# how to use '*' in XPATH starts-with()?

Tags: regex, xpath, sonarqube

we received banking statements from the SAP System. We sometimes observe the naming convention of the file name will be not as per the standards and the files will be rejected.
We wanted to validate the file name, as per the below example, we get the file name in the **name** attribute.

Can the country ISO code escape in the validation?
We wanted an Xpath that captures GLO_***_UPLOAD_STATEMENT like this so that ISO code is not validated.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details name="GLO_ZFA_UPLOAD_STATEMENT" type="banking" version="3.0">
    <description/>
    <object>
        <encrypted data="b528f05b96102f5d99743ff6122bb0984aa16a02893984a9e427a44fcedae1612104a7df1173d9c61a99ebe0c34ea67a46aecc86f41f5924f74dd525"/>
    </object>
</Details>
```

Xpath tried:
`Details[@type="banking"]/@name[not(starts-with(., "GLO_***_UPLOAD_STATEMENT"))]`

which is not working :(

Can anyone help here, please :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use regex in combination with starts-with

Comment: `starts-with(., "GLO_") and ends_with(., "_UPLOAD_STATEMENT")`

Comment: @choroba Answers go in the answer boxes below, not in comments.

Comment: Current browsers only support XPath 1.0, not 2.0.

Comment: The question was originally tagged `xpath-2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the matches() function for a regex like this:

```
Details[@type="banking"]/@name[not(matches(., "^GLO_(.){3}_UPLOAD_STATEMENT"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match regular expressions using the matches() function. For example:

```
//Details[@type="banking" and not(matches(@name, "GLO_[A-Z]*_UPLOAD_STATEMENT"))]/@name
```

Will only select Details node's name attribute for Details that have type="banking" and name not matching the regular expression "GLO_[A-Z]*_UPLOAD_STATEMENT".  You can refine the regex as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`starts-with()` is char based, it doesn't recognize patterns.

If your XPath version doesn't support regex then you can use something like:

```
Details[@type="banking"]/@name[not(starts-with(., "GLO_")) and not(ends-with(., "_UPLOAD_STATEMENT"))]
```

Comment: If you have `ends-with` you should have `matches` as well, I think, as both are of XPath 2.0 and later.